# Unknown column '1' in 'field list'

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am trying to insert data into my stop table the `stops` table as well as the `route` table are being created, but the program fails to insert the data into the stop table, and I am getting this error:

```
Unknown column '1' in 'field list'
```

I appreciate any help.

```
    stt.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS routes"
             + "(route_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, "
             + "route INT(11) NOT NULL)" );
    stt.execute("INSERT INTO routes(route) VALUES"
            + "(1),"
            + "(9)");

    stt.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stops"
            + "(stop_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, "
            + " name varchar(30) NOT NULL, "
            + " lat double(10,6) NOT NULL, "
            + " longi double(10,6)NOT NULL,"
            + "route_id INT, FOREIGN KEY fk_route_id(route_id) REFERENCES routes(route_id) )" );

    stt.execute("INSERT INTO stops(route_id, name,  lat, longi) VALUES"
            + "(`1`, 'Alex allee', '83.868937', '18.665545' ),"                     
            + "(`1`,'city street', '83.840642', '18.701246' )," 
            + "(`2`,'apple street', '83.740642', '18.761246' ),"
            + "(`2`,'wall street', '83.868256', '18.669520' )");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For escaping strings you hae to use single quotes. backtick are needed for column or table names. For numerical there is no escape charater nesassary.

because your `route_id` values are escape by backticks mysql interpreting it as a column name. remove them and your query will work.

```
stt.execute("INSERT INTO stops(route_id, name,  lat, longi) VALUES"
            + "(1, 'Alex allee', 83.868937, 18.665545 ),"                     
            + "(1,'city street', 83.840642, 18.701246 )," 
            + "(9,'apple street', 83.740642, 18.761246 ),"
            + "(9,'wall street', 83.868256, 18.669520 )");
```

Comment: It works now but it is realy strange because I have another table with  foreign key and I instert the data there like this `INSERT INTO arrivaltimes(stop_id, weekday, arrivaltime, route) values
( '1', 'mon-fri', '12:25', '1' )` and it works?!

Comment: @MrAsker here you have single quotes around your numerical values. This will be converted automatically

Comment: Also for the error earlier  I have just removed the single quotes from the first column and it works and not from the lat and longi.

Comment: @MrAsker in your original error you have no single quotes around first value that are backticks!! You can add single quotes around numerical values. But it is no good practice because the sql interpreter must convert it. That need time and the query will be slow.